# Plot range not expanding

Tags: plotting

Im trying to make an ellipse of a parametric plot in mathematica. This is what I have so far:

```
x[t_] := 2.5 + 1.5 Cos[π/3 t];
y[t_] := 2.4 + 1.1 Sin[π/3 t];
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

My problem is that the range won't change outside of [0,1] for x and y, but the function I have is outside of this; specifically within the region x: [1,4], y: [1,4] which I know because I graphed it on Desmos. 
I've tried setting the `PlotRange` option to `All`, `Full`, and `Automatic`, but none of those change anything.

How do I change my range to include the given ellipse?

Comment: You are plotting in a wrong way: see this https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html

Comment: To expand on what @math said, your call to `ParametricPlot` should specify the range of values *for the parameter* $t$, not for $x$ and $y$: `ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` will plot the ellipse and automatically select an appropriate plot range.